# Symbols in APL package

Tags: symbols

The following does not work (MikTeX):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{apl}
\begin{document}
\AB
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Font \apl=cmapl10 not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file \def
I can't find file `versatim' \input versatim
```

How can I get the symbols in the APL package to work? The symbols are listed ok in the Latex Comprehensive Symbol List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `versatim.tex` file was put by error in   `doc\latex\apl\`. Move it to `\tex\latex\apl\`.

As to the problem of the metric file, you can create a  new one with the following command line:

```
  mf \mode=localfont ; input cmapl10
```

This produces  3 files: `cmapl10.log, cmapl.600gf` and `cmapl10.tfm`. Delete the first two and move the `tfm` file into `\fonts\tfm\public\apl`.

Finally, refresh the FNDB.

[image]

Comment: I reported this [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2470).